# (awk) Remove lines containing two or more specific words

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have this:

```
awk -v p="WORD1" 'FNR==1{x=0}{x+=gsub(p,p);if(x>1){print FILENAME;nextfile}}' *
```

This finds files that contain the word WORD1 two or more times.
Could you please tell me how to remove these lines (which contain the word WORD1 two or more times) from the file?

Thank you!

Comment: please update the question with sample input (include lines with no matches, 1 match, 2+ matches) and the expected output (corresponding to the sample input)

Comment: If `BADWORD1` exists in the input - should that be counted as occurrence of `WORD1` or not?

Comment: For example, I need to find and delete lines with the word "santaclaus" (which occurs two or more times in one line) in all txt files

Comment: `grep -v "WORD1.*WORD1" file` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please tell me how to remove these lines (which contain the word WORD1 two or more times) from the file

If you have `gnu-awk` then you can use this solution:

```bash
awk -i inplace -F '\\<WORD1\\>' 'NF <= 2' *
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my side, maybe you made some mistake? Please check again

Comment: I posted a properly tested solution. Did you check your awk version?

Comment: I have "GNU Awk 4.0.2"

Comment: And what error did you get? btw you should also post sample input with expected output in question.

Comment: There is no specific error, after entering your command I get a short instruction on how to use awk: "...Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ......".    For example, I need to find and delete lines with the word "santaclaus" (which occurs two or more times in one line) in all txt files

Comment: Ok may be your `awk` doesn't support `-i inplace` option. Does `awk -F '\\<WORD1\\>' 'NF <= 2' *` show some output?

Comment: this command shows the contents of the file

Comment: But that output will have lines removed that have more than 1 occurrence of `WORD1`. You need to upgrade your gnu-awk to a later version to be able to use `-i inplace` option

Comment: awk -F '\\<WORD1\\>' 'NF <= 2' *  -  working perfectly! May I know please what is your awk version? Because with "-i inplace" it doesn't work.

Comment: I am on gnu-awk 5.1.1. You need at least 4.2.1 to use `inplace` option

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/(\<\S+\>).*\<\1\>/d' file
```

If a word repeats twice in a line, delete the line.

Comment: how to specify a specific word for example "santaclaus"?

Comment: replace `\S+` with the specific word

Answer (score 0):

Sample input:

```
$ cat sample.dat
this line has 0 entries
this line has 1 WORD1 entry
this line has 2 WORD1 WORD1 entries
this line has 3 WORD1 WORD1 WORD1 entries
```

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk -v p="WORD1" 'gsub(p,p)<=1' sample.dat
this line has 0 entries
this line has 1 WORD1 entry
```

If:

- results are correct and ...
- OP wants to overwrite the input file and ...
- OP has `GNU awk`

Then OP can add `-i inplace`, eg:

```
$ awk -v p="WORD1" -i inplace 'gsub(p,p)<=1' sample.dat
```

If OP's `awk` doesn't support `-i inplace` then the output can be saved to a temp file and then `mv tmpfile sample.dat`.

---

One potential issue with `gsub(p,p)` ... this will cause `WORD1` to match on `BADWORD123`; if OP only wants a 'whole word' match then we need to add a bit more code.

Updating our sample input:

```
$ cat sample.dat
this line has 0 entries
this line has 1 WORD1 entry
this line has 2 WORD1 WORD1 entries
this line has 3 WORD1 WORD1 WORD1 entries
this line has 1 WORD1 BADWORD12 entry
WORD1 this line has 2 matching entries WORD1
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v p="WORD1" '

function regex_cnt() {
    c=0
    x=$0
    while (match(x,regex)) {
          c++
          x=substr(x,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
    } 
    return c
}

BEGIN { regex="(^|[^[:alnum:]])" p "([^[:alnum:]]|$)" }   # add checks for beginning-of-line, non-alphanumeric and end-of-line to our regex

regex_cnt()<=1
' sample.dat
```

This generates:

```
this line has 0 entries
this line has 1 WORD1 entry
this line has 1 WORD1 BADWORD12 entry
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to remove these lines (which contain the word WORD1 two or more
> times) from the file?

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
zero
one WORD1
one WORD1 two WORD1
one WORD1 two WORD1 three WORD1
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="WORD1"}NF<2' file.txt
```

gives output

```
zero
one WORD1
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is string matching pattern `WORD1`, then select lines which have less 2 fields (`NF` holds number of fields). Keep in mind that `FPAT` value is regular expression, so if your word containg character of special meaning (e.g. dot) you have to escape them.

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)